# Video Mute/Unmute

Tags: javascript, html, css

Not that great at javascript, but I've had my head through so many desks at this point trying to make this video unmute and mute upon being clicked.

```
<HTML class="scroll">
<Head>
<LINK REL="StyleSheet" HREF="ARCHDRAGONCSS.css">
    <Title>ArchDragon</Title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var check=1;
        var Mandala = document.getElementById("Mandala");           
        function toggleSound(check){
            if(check==1){                     
                check=0;
                Mandala.muted=true;

            }
            else{ 
                check=1;
                Mandala.muted=false;

            }
        }
    </script>
</Head>
<BR>
<Img Src="ArchDragonLogo.png" ID="ArchDragon">
<BR>
<Body Align=Middle  class="Index">
<iFrame Src="Header.html" ID="Head" allowTransparency="true"></iFrame>
<Div>
<video id="Mandala" src="mandala.mp4" autoplay="true" loop="true" muted onclick="toggleSound(check);"></video>
</Div>
<BR>
<BR>
<iFrame src="home.html" name="iDisplay" ID="main"></iFrame>

</Body>
```

Comment: Your DOM isn’t loaded when `var Mandala = document.getElementById("Mandala");` is declared.

Comment: I agree with the above **&** `onclick="toggleSound(check);"` should be `onclick="toggleSound('0');"` OR `onclick="toggleSound('1');"` I'm going to assume it should be set to `0` since your have `muted` in your video tag. You also have page elements outside of your `body` tag. This won't cause an error but I would recommend keeping your html/page elements inside of your body tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is this:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){ // make sure DOM is loaded
  document.getElementById("Mandala").addEventListener('click',function(){
    this.muted=!this.muted; // toggle
  });
});
```

as the whole script.

Then you also can remove that `onclick` inline event handler from the HTML.

This plus keeping a [valid HTML](https://validator.w3.org/).